# trouble with installing rvm in ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I just installed rvm in my machine using the following command

```
bash < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer )
```

and got this in my terminal

```
Installation of RVM to /home/rahul/.rvm/ is complete.
```

When I go to `/home/rahul/.rvm/`, I am able to see all the necessary folders but when I give rvm command in the terminal, I get this error

```
 rvm --version
No command 'rvm' found, but there are 19 similar ones
rvm: command not found
```

How can I fix it?

EDIT

I have also added the following lines in my bashrc

```
if [[ -n "$PS1" ]]; then
if [[ -s $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] ; then source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ; fi
fi
```

Comment: Can you give the output of `where rvm` and `$PATH`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RVM on Ubuntu Troubles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020214/rvm-on-ubuntu-troubles)

Comment: try to read `rvm notes` if you did'nt yet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you reload your shell or open a new terminal window?

Did you follow the diagnostics on [the RVM install page](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/), in particular the section "Troubleshooting Your Install", checking to see if RVM is known as a function? You should see something like this:

```
user$ type rvm | head -1
rvm is a function
```

Answer (score 13):

actually after installation of rvm , you have to run the script. i was stuck in the same level as you are, than in terminal i read this line:

*"  To start using RVM you need to run `source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm` "*

so place this command (`source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm`) in terminal and enter

and after that :

```
type rvm | head -1
rvm is a function (this you will see hopefully)
```

Comment: bash: type: rvm: not found

Comment: Ah, thank you so much. I missed the running `source ...` part.

Answer (score 4):

You should add `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` in `~/.bashrc`, and restart terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal go to `Edit` > `Profile Preferences` click on `Title and Command` tab and check `Run command as login shell`.

[**Find out the tutorial**](https://github.com/rvm/ubuntu_rvm#2-change-your-terminal-window)